# Write a program to count the number of times that the character "a" appears anywhere in the file JavaIntro.txt.

Tags: java, count

I am trying to figure out how to count all of the numbers into 1 counter this counts the number of 'a' from each line and displays each line I want to know how to count all of them onto one line.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CountTheNumberOfAs {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {

        String fileName = "JavaIntro.txt";
        String line = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {

          while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            int counter = 0;

            for( int i=0; i<line.length(); i++ ) {
                if( line.charAt(i) == 'a' ) {
                    counter++; 

                } 


            }

             System.out.println(counter);   
          }
        }
        finally {

          scanner.close();


    }}}
```

Comment: A debugger would be a great help in finding errors like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the counter outside of the while loop. (same for the print):

```
int counter = 0;
while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
// ...
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: I tried that it just counts 1 2 3 on individual lines.. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you removed those line from their previous place?

Comment: yes removed the originals and then placed them outside the while loop

Comment: I decided to put the counts into a new file and then read the new file to calculate the sum.. It works while not pretty it works, ha.